# Gmail API keeps returning error 500 Backend Error for a particular email address

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

For a while it's been working fine. Now today, all of a sudden, when I try to list messages for a particular email address the API call just hangs for a while and then returns Backend Error (500). It still works sometimes, and sometimes it's just really slow at responding, but for the most part it seems to hang.

Any ideas what the problem could be, or how to diagnose it. I'm using the node, googleapis package, oauth2 tokens, server-side calls.

PS: I've checked the logs and there aren't any 4xx errors.

Comment: Considering you have a stable net connection, I think this might be a matter of code implementation as [Users.messages.list Try-it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#top_of_page) is working consistently fine. Posting your code might help shed a light on your problem.

Comment: I think the reason I was receiving 500 was probably because of too many calls or too many concurrent connections - which is a bit strange since I would expect to receive a 4xx status code for that instead of 500

Comment: If that is the case, try setting a time interval for each request.

Comment: I've limited my calls to max 10 concurrently and I haven't received the error since :)

Comment: smart move, you can share that snippet here for the community if you want :)